# How can I get marker details after that is added to the map?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

I'm using [this library](https://smeijer.github.io/leaflet-geosearch/) in a vue project that is implementing leaflet.
I need to get the added marker when an user will select an address after that the library have found the desired location. I've tried using this code but without success. I've also found [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226319/how-to-detect-when-new-markers-have-been-added-to-the-leaflet-map) but not helped at all.

This is whatI'm using at the moment to try get the marker info

```js
this.map.on('layer', (e) => {
    console.log(e)
})
```

in a method I'm initializing leaflet in this way

```js
initLeaflet() {
    this.map = Leaflet.map('map')
        .setView([51.505, -0.09], 13)
        Leaflet.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        //attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(this.map)
    //
    const searchControl = new GeoSearchControl({
        provider: new OpenStreetMapProvider(),
        style: 'bar',
    });
    this.map.addControl(searchControl)
},
```

How I can correctly get the desired information so I can get the latitude and longitude of the selected point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [popupFormat](https://github.com/smeijer/leaflet-geosearch) option to display the longitude and latitude of the found location in a popup as in [the jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/j6c1f9ze/):

[image: open street map with search bar]

```js
'use strict';

var myMap = L.map('mapId').setView([-23.9608, -46.3331], 13);
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(myMap);

var search = new GeoSearch.GeoSearchControl({
  provider: new GeoSearch.OpenStreetMapProvider(),
  style: 'bar',
  showPopup: true,
  popupFormat: ({
      query,
      result
    }) =>
    'longitude: ' + parseFloat(result.x).toFixed(6) +
    ', latitude: ' + parseFloat(result.y).toFixed(6)
});

myMap.addControl(search);
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#mapId {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1/dist/leaflet.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1/dist/leaflet-src.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-geosearch@3/dist/bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-geosearch@3/dist/geosearch.min.css">

<div id="mapId"></div>
```